# Why is Gambit a valuable member of the X-Men if his powers are very limited?

Tags: marvel, x-men, mutant

Gambit has the power of charging objects with kinetic energy, making them explode. He mostly uses that power to charge play cards and throw them at opponents, on which they explode with the power of a hand grenade.

Many X-Men have superpowers to create blast effects or fire energy blasts that cause more damage than a hand grenade. For example, Cyclops' energy blast can destroy a Sentinel while Gambit's cards cannot.

Why has Gambit's character become so popular and why he is considered a valuable member of the X-Men if his superpowers are so limited and even inferior compared to other X-Men members?

Remark: I ask the question after I saw a Facebook discussion about a painting showing Gambit fighting the Incredible Hulk.

Comment: Why single out Gambit? What about Jubilee, or the Beast, or the Angel?

Comment: Beast's main "power" is his intelligence. Jubilee is indeed considered a junior member and is not as popular as Gambit.

Comment: The Beast's scientific prowess is only mainly useful in a lab. It doesn't make much difference on the battlefield, where he mostly relies on his physical prowess.

Comment: Many of the x-men have powers that can basically be replicated with weaponry or tech

Comment: Grenades are expensive, _cherie_

Comment: Yes, but an eyes-generated energy blast is cheaper than playing cards and causes much more damage to the target.

Comment: I think the real answer is *because it's cool*

Comment: You're asking two separate questions: (1) Why is Gambit so popular (for the readers) (2) Why is Gambit a valuable member of the X-Men (for the X-Men). The answer to (1) is pretty much unrelated to Gambit's powers. Of course, if Gambit is popular with the readers, then he has to be a member of the X-Men, so the answer to (2) is just going to be a made-up pretext.

Comment: @Triceratops I don't believe Cyclops' ruby visor is less expensive than playing cards.

Comment: @Triceratops - _"an eyes-generated energy blast is cheaper than playing cards and causes much more damage to the target."_ So what? It's not as if the X-Men had to kick Cyclops off the team to allow Gambit on it. If they had to choose between the two, they probably would pick Cyke, but they don't have to make a choice like that, because they can have both if both are willing and available.

Comment: Your argument against Gambit's usefulness is bit like asking why a charity would bother accepting small donations when they have access to larger ones. Sure, the larger donations are more useful, but that doesn't mean the smaller ones aren't useful too. The charity (and the cause it was set up to help) would be worse off overall if it rejected small donations rather than taking all donations.

Comment: You can also take it from the point of view of the x men who would be willing to take any mutant they could find as they did not want them to get into magneto's influence or use their powers for harm just as gambit was using before he joined the team

Comment: This question reminds me of when, as a kid, I was wondering why the Justice League had people like Batman, Green Arrow and The Question, instead of merely having an army of Supermen. The answer was: because they don't have an army of Supermen, and being picky kind of narrowed the team down. I'm not writing this as an answer because it's just a personal interpretation.

Comment: Is Gambit limited to his mutant power though? Isn't there something he has which the others don't? Like, for example, I don't know, charisma? Being a [Face](https://shadowrun.fandom.com/wiki/Face) (someone with good social skills in the Shadowrun universe)?

Comment: Related: [Ex-Men: Gambit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSfpEG3SFc8) (Pete Holmes sketch)

Answer (score 9):

### Gambit is extremely powerful and useful

He doesn't use his full power on every throw of his cards, and he doesn't currently have access to his full power either. But by all accounts he has the potential to be omega level – at one point he requested Mr Sinister to help him control his powers, and have a bit of his brain removed (X-Men Origins: Gambit #2. Marvel Comics).

An alternative version of him called New Sun, one without the brain surgery, visits from an alternate reality and is shown to be extremely powerful (Gambit vol. 3 #23).

Along with this, Gambit has a host of other abilities that make him useful to the X-Men, as listed in this [respect thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/respectthreads/comments/71escu/respect_gambit_marvel_616/):

> Gambit can increase or accelerate the kinetic energy of an object by touching it. Increasing an object's kinetic energy, or "charging" it, has different applications, but Gambit most often charges throwing cards and other inanimate objects so that they explode. Gambit's innate biokinetic energy also grants passive powers such as him superhuman agility, telepathic resistance, and charm.

In summary, he's definitely able to pull his weight, but knows when and how to best apply his powers rather than just use brute force every time.

Comment: AncientSwordRage: _"Gambit is extremely powerful and useful"_ Thor (squinting): _"Is he, though?"_

Comment: The biokinetic energy gives him "charm"?   If only it worked that way in real life, lol.

Comment: @MarkRogers It certainly gives him strange.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the X-men are assembled like a basketball team where the one with the best skillset in each area is chosen, and the rest are "benched." Most of them grew up with Prof X and the others as their family, and those that are able bodied and willing to fight and go on missions are allowed to do so (provided they've demonstrated a minimum level of combat skill in the Danger Room).

Comment: I don't think there is any version of Gambit that fits the grew up with the x-men back story. So I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: "I don't think the X-men are assembled like a basketball team" — [counterpoint!](https://townsquare.media/site/622/files/2013/12/XMen081.jpg?w=630&h=471&q=75)

Answer (score 3):

The strength of Cyclops' ability can be an advantage in some situations, such as facing a Sentinel, but in a lot of cases, it's a liability. Cyclops is in a constant state of just barely not lasering everyone around him to death. The fact that he has been in so many fights in which he didn't kill anyone is due to a massive amount of plot armor, and that plot armor obscures just how dangerous his power is. His laser beams have pretty much unlimited range, which is useful for hitting people far away, but also means that everyone around him needs to make sure that they aren't standing behind his target.

Gambit can throw cards around corners, hit multiple targets at once, and provide the team with the option of non-lethal force. And pull off finger-less gloves. He also have powers often ignored by the writers, such as slight psychic abilities that he can use to charm people.

Moreover, in comic-book stories, pretty much anyone can be useful. Even if Gambit goes against someone who can defeat him, while that opponent is dealing with Gambit, they are distracted  from the rest of the fight.

As for why people are fans of him, he is a distinctive character, and fans are motivated by things other than power level.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the X-Men team is akin to a team of firefighters.

Would you refuse an eligible new recruit on the basis that you already have someone in the team who is capable of doing everything the recruit can do? Or would you rather have an extra capable pair of hands to fight against the blazing fire when there are lives at stakes?

Comparing their powers individually might show that the others are more effective than he can ever be. Cyclops for example might have more firepower, but that does not mean Gambit or anyone else whom you deem to have weaker power cannot give a hand. After all, in a real fight, you don't always get to pick your champion and have them fight the opponent on 1 versus 1 like in a video game.

Now, consider that people are more than just their mutant abilities. There was this episode from [X-Men: Evolution (2000)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3A_Evolution) animated series, titled *Cajun Spice*. Gambit, who wasn't part from the X-Men had kidnapped Rogue from the X-Men team. He pretended it was for her own good, when in truth it was for his own benefit. To me, this shows that he knows his way with words and can small talk you into giving in. That can be either considered as **charisma** or **manipulation**; something which I hardly saw with the other X-men characters.

Comment: I won't answer the popularity question because that sounds opinion based.

Comment: Another example I remember is from _Wolverine and the X-Men_ in which Gambit had manipulated one of Magneto's daughter by playing with her feelings to get what he wanted, although I don't remember the details.

Answer (score -2):

While the X-Men have no shortage of experienced melee fighters with energy powers, he's still notable among that group.